# Order of growth for g(x)

Tags: function, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

```
int f (int x)
{
      if (x < 1)  return 1;
      else return (f(x-1) + g(x));
}

int g (int x)
{
      if (x < 2) return 2;
      else return (f(x-1) + g(x/2));
}
```

How to calculate the order of growth for g(x) here?

Comment: This seems like a pure math problem for me, so I suggest to move the question.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating order of `f` and `g` we need to calculate both and the worst order is the answer because they are adding to each other in both function. for example between `n` and `n/2` , `n` is the worst so the order is `n`.

Whenever `f` is called it's `f(x-1)` , then the order is `n`. and in `g` function we have `g(x/2)` that it means the order of `g(x/2)` is `n/2` because `x` divided by `2` every time.

So in `g` we have order `n` + `n/2` and the worst order is `n` so the result of *"order of `g(x)`"* is `n`.